# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC error in java netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to connect from Java to SQLite. When I run it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

This is my code:

```
public static Connection ConnectDb(){
    try{
        Class.forName("Org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Malmuo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\VotersVerificationSys\\verifyvoters.sqlite");
      return conn;  
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the exception it looks like NB is not aware of the driver for sqlite.

Comment: also, i think it should be org.sqlite.JDBC not Org.sqlite.JDBC (upper case O)

Comment: Duplicate. There are many already asked questions with good answers for classNotFoundExceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly this needs to be corrected:

```
Class.forName("Org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

to

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

- Download the SQLite jar from [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.10.1/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar)
- Add the SQLite jar to your Project buildpath/classpath so that the necessary class can be loaded from that jar.

  - Open Eclipse Project Properties
  - Buildpath
  - Add the jar that you've downloaded from the step above.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks so much, my problem has been corrected. Just for changing ("Org.sqlite.JDBC") to ("org.sqlite.JDBC") lower cases. Thanks once again may God bless you

Comment: @Peter, Happy to help! Would you mind accepting my answer as it solved your issue?